# C error Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF6F56C2317 in cpp2.exe: 0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000018664F3000)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2022

This is a small program I wrote on Visual Studio 2022 to learn C. It is compiled well, and executed. But when I run the code it return that error message behind `int main() {` and just don't let me run it.
Anyone help me with this please, I have no idea what to do now.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void arrin(float x[1000][1000], int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < m;j++) {
            scanf_s("%f", &x[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
void arrout(float x[1000][1000], int n, int m) {
    for (int i = 0;i < n;i++) {
        for (int j = 0;j < m;j++) {
            printf("%f ", x[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main() {
    float a[1000][1000];
    int n, m;

    printf("insert number of rows: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    printf("insert number of cols: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &m);

    arrin(a, n, m);
    arrout(a, n, m);
    return 0;
}
```

I looked for others posts about this but still ran into dead end. I tried running it on https://www.onlinegdb.com/ and it run normally.

Comment: You shouldn't declare huge arrays like that on the stack. That's 4 million bytes and the Windows stack is 1Mb or so. If you really need an array that big, use `static` or dynamic memory allocation.

Comment: @Lundin ohh I tried smaller array and it worked!! Thanks for your informations!!